# Ping my URL from a different location

Tags: networking, ping, url, latency

Is there a way to someway mirror a ping request to an URL, to test it's speed from a different location?

Say I'm in US and want to request a ping to my website coming from India and check the latency. Do I have to use a third-part service, or can I forge my own process?

Comment: Search for "ping server india" => http://startping.com/country/India. You can also start from may other places => http://startping.com/map/

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a computer in the location(s) you want to ping from. Since you probably don't own a computer in India that you can access, then a third party service is probably best (and easiest, and cheapest).

Something like CA's APM Could Monitor's Ping tool (formerly www.just-ping.com) should do it for you; there are many out there to choose from, most easily locatable with a little searching.

Answer (score 0):

Have you googled even the word ping? there are many sites which will allow you to ping a host from their site.
ping.eu will give you alot more services (traceroute, whois, traceroute, even port checks.

Comment: Actually, I did... But I just wanted to be sure if I could do it myself instead of using another service...

Comment: As Techie said you need a computer from where you want to ping from. You can pick up a free unix shell account, which will give you access to a unix box somewhere in the world and you can ping it from there also.